# Crystal Reports for VS2012 – free or not?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

Since Visual Studio 2010 **Crystal Reports** are no longer part of Visual Studio.
I'm using **Visual Studio 2012 Professional** and despite checking various sources I cannot reliably determine whether I can

1. *freely* download and use **Crystal Reports Developer version** for development of commercial applications in **Visual Studio 2012**
2. *freely* distribute and install **Crystal Reports Runtime** for running apps (developed above) at clients

In other words, do I need to purchase a license or not? Do clients need purchase their licenses, too?

(Besides your answer, providing link to sources of information will be appreciated.)

*FYI - For obtaining Crystal Reports, there is a [great resource containing all versions and package types](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824), but still leaving me without the answer.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, **basic solutions**, that allow a **developer** to generate and deploy reports, **are free**.
**Advanced solutions**, that allow **end user** to create, edit and share reports **are not free**.

- It is free the IDE to be used with Visual Studio; stand alone full IDE is not free
- Crystal Reports Runtime for running apps is free. SAP Crystal Server is not free.

---

EDIT

Look at this article: [How do you spell confusion; CR for VS, Crystal 2011, BI 4.x and the .NET SDKs](http://scn.sap.com/community/crystal-reports-for-visual-studio/blog/2013/06/28/how-do-you-spell-confussion-cr-for-vs-crystal-2011-bi-4x-and-the-net-sdks)

> And "Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2010" (CRVS2010) is born. Note that this version, follows in the footsteps of CR 10.5; it only works in the VS 2010 IDE. E.g.; it is not a stand alone executable like CR XI R2 or CR 2008. CRVS 2010 has both 32 bit and 64 bit runtime. And it has the Crystal Reports SDK for .NET as well as the InProc RAS SDK. And it's FREE(!).

Comment: Do you think there is a subpage of *sap.com* where the statement about free availability can be seen? [Home page of Crystal Reports](https://www.sap.com/solution/sme/software/analytics/crystal-reports/index.html) is all but not clear at this point. I can see only 30-day trial version offered.

Comment: I'm awarding this asnwer, but for *more exact* explanation of free licensing conditions, please refer to answer starting with "*It seems that Crystal Reports licensing depends on many factors.*" and to source document referred therein.

Comment: _Crystal Reports has been automatically installed as a part of Visual Basic. It was also included in Visual Studio up to the version Visual Studio 2008.  It was removed from the Visual Studio 2010 and now available as separate download._

`Crystal Reports was renamed as SAP Crystal Reports for Visual studio. You can download the Crystal report for Visual Studio from the following link`
***Latest Download: 
SAP Crystal Reports for Visual Studio (Version 13.0.18.2192) Support Pack 18***

Comment: _This is the latest Version of SAP Crystal Reports for Visual studio. It Works on Visual Studio 2010, Visual Studio 2012, Visual Studio 2013 & Visual Studio 2015_

***SAP Crystal Reports for Visual studio is Free and you can download it and use it for your reporting requirements***

Answer (score 3):

It seems that Crystal Reports licensing depends on many factors. There is a [blog from an SAP employee: "SAP Crystal Licensing for Humans"](http://scn.sap.com/people/blair.wheadon/blog/2011/04/11/sap-crystal-licensing-for-humans) which puts the information together and covers most cases. The entire simplified licensing whitepaper referred there has **20** pages. Currently the document is up-to-date also for 2013 releases.

Based on the above document (esp. page **4**) the answer is that

SAP Crystal Reports for Visual Studio **is free if** Crystal Reports is used

- **internally** in company (external users can also access, but no access fee can be charged to them)

-or-

- with **runtime engine deployed only on client machines**, i.e. all report processing is done locally on client machine. Also **no parallel access** to such a client runtime is allowed (also including Citrix or Remote Desktop usage).

For additional information, please check that document.

Answer (score 2):

Please see this [post](http://scn.sap.com/message/14222986) and the licensing information from SAP [here](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/go/portal/prtroot/docs/library/uuid/70bd6328-4128-2d10-7882-d7b95418dbaa?QuickLink=index&overridelayout=true&58600533788909) to answer your questions.
Basically the answer to both questions is "Yes".
You can download the developer version [here](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-35074).

Comment: link is broken :(
where can I download the developer version?